# Concurrency handling correct?

Tags: java, concurrency

Proxy will be called from multiple thread, and Proxy.setWorker() may be called at some time, does anyone know if below implementation will cause problem?

```
class Worker {
    void methodA() {
        ...
    }
    
    void methodB() {
        ...
    }
};
```

… and …

```
class Proxy {
    volatile Worker mWorker;
    final boolean cond= true;
    
    public void setWorker(Worker worker) {
        mWorker = worker;
    }
    void methodA() {
        if(cond)
            mWorker.methodA();
    }
    
    void methodB() {
        if(cond)
            mWorker.methodB();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Provided `cond` is not modified somewhere else, this looks ok.

Comment: cond is not modified

Comment: If `cond` is not modified while the threads are working, why have it? To me that var looks like a flag to be modified and accessed across threads. If so, this code is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a data race when there are 2 threads doing a read/write or write/write to the same field and these reads/writes are not ordered by the happens-before relation (so there is no happens-before edge between them).

The 'worker' field is volatile, so there is a happens-before edge due to the volatile variable rule; hence, there is no data-race.

I would make the 'cond' field final if possible to prevent confusion. If you would modify the 'cond' field, then your code could have a data-race unless you make it volatile.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you have a separate Proxy for each thread.  If you do you are fine.  If you don't and you try and call setWorker from two places at the same or if you try and one of the methods while setting the worker or if either of the methods modify proxy or worker you will have some data race issues.

Comment: The proxy is shared by multiple threads and it's possible the setWorker and two method may be called simultaneously. If you could elaborate what race issue it is would be great.

Comment: A data race is when two pieces you are trying to access and set the same piece of data from 2 threads at the same time.  This will result in unexpected behavior.  If you call setWorker and one of the methods at the same time, when you run the program sometimes the setWorker will be called before method, or sometimes it will do the opposite, call the method before the setWorker.

Comment: I don't see the data race. Object reference assignment in Java is atomic. The only issue is that one thread may be using the old `Worker` previously assigned to `mWorker` while another thread may be using the `Worker` currently assigned to `mWorker`. Or is that worker assignment the data race to which you refer? If so, I suggest you add more explanation to the Answer.

Comment: Since the object assignment is atomic, so the code looks good to for concurrent usage. It's not an issue for one thread use old worker instance when setWorker is called

Comment: There is no data race on the worker field. The accesses are conflicting (read/write or write/write issued by 2 different threads to the same location), but they are ordered by a happens-before edge due to 'worker' being volatile. And this implies there is no data-race.

Comment: Even though object assignment is treated atomic (so you can't end up with an address that is the mixture of 2 writes), it doesn't mean you can't have a data-race on a reference field.